# Binary search tree insertion in c

Tags: c

insert operation is not happening for BST.can cause?-1 is null element in array.
Linked list is not be for this code.

```
void insert(int *Tree,int element)
{
    int temp=0;/* first subscript*/

    if(Tree[temp]==-1){

        Tree[temp]=element;
        return;
    }

    while(1){
        if((Tree[temp]>element))
            if (Tree[2*temp+1]==-1){
                Tree[2*temp+1]==element;
                break;
            }
            else
                temp=2*temp+1;

            else if(Tree[2*temp+2]==-1){
                Tree[2*temp+2]==element;
                break;
            }

            else
                temp=2*temp+2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Tree[2*temp+1]==element` isn't going to do much by way of *assignment*. Likewise for `Tree[2*temp+2]==element`. Oh copy-paste!, ye are a cruel and heartless wench.

Comment: Did you properly allocate enough space, and is every element initialized to `-1`? What happens if `temp` gets larger than the size of the tree?... Did you notice any compiler warnings?

Comment: Wow @WhozCraig - you going poetic on us? Still - good eye. Close as "typo"?

Comment: @Floris Did indeed vote as such. Lord knows if the algorithm is right. Didn't even bother checking. =P

Comment: @user3403833 I recommend adding curly braces for EVERY `if` and `else` - even if they are just one statement long. Right now you have a long `if-else` wrapped inside another `if`, which is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the indentation, adding braces, and the replacing the `==` used for assignment (should be `=`), your code works OK-ish. Still would like to add a check to make sure you don't exceed the size of `tree`...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert(int *Tree,int element)
{
    int temp=0;/* first subscript*/

    if(Tree[temp]==-1){

        Tree[temp]=element;
        return;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if((Tree[temp]>element))
        {
          if (Tree[2*temp+1]==-1)
          {
            Tree[2*temp+1]=element;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            temp=2*temp+1;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          if(Tree[2*temp+2]==-1)
          {
            Tree[2*temp+2]=element;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            temp=2*temp+2;
          }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
  int tree[100];
  int ii;
  for(ii=0;ii<100;ii++) tree[ii]=-1;
  insert(tree, 5);
  insert(tree, 3);
  insert(tree, 9);
  insert(tree, 4);
  for(ii=0; ii<10; ii++) printf("%d: %d\n", ii, tree[ii]);
}
```

Whether this actually produces the tree you are looking for is something I cannot guess.

Comment: +1 You *can too* guess =(in fact, thats about all you can do given this =} )

Comment: @Floris successful solution thank you very muchhh

Comment: @YavuzGiran glad to help. *Do* take my comment about always using `{}` to heart... and always turn on compiler warnings - it should be screaming at your for the `==`. (my gcc compiler does).